# Is $S_M(0,1)$ always homeomorphic to the unit sphere of $E$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space, with inner product $\langle\cdot\;| \;\cdot\rangle$ and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and let $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$. Let  $M\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ (i.e.$M^*=M$ and $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$).

Assume that $M$ is an injective operator on $E$, so $x\longmapsto \langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle$ is a norm on $E$.

> Consider
>   $$S(0,1)=\{x\in E;\;\|x\|=1\}$$
>   and
>   $$S_M(0,1)=\{x\in E;\;\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle=1\}$$
>   Is $S_M(0,1)$ always homeomorphic to $S(0,1)$ even if $E$ is an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **FINAL ANSWER** [Due to Student; see comments]. The two sets are homeomorphic because the maps
>   $$ h\colon x\in S\mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{\langle Mx, x\rangle}}\in S_M,\qquad g\colon y\in S_M\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|}\in S$$
>   are continuous and the inverse of each other. We use the assumptions on $M$ in order to ensure that $h$ is well-defined and continuous.

*Remark*. If $V$ is a vector space and $\|\cdot\|_1, \|\cdot\|_2$ are two norms on it, with unit spheres $S_1, S_2$ respectively, then the maps 
$$ h_{i,j}(x_i)=\frac{x_i}{\|x_i\|_j},\qquad i\ne j,$$ 
are bijections of $S_i$ onto $S_j$ such that $h_{i,j}^{-1}=h_{j, i}$. If one of the norms is continuous with respect to the other then the maps are homeomorphisms.

---

**PREVIOUS VERSION OF THIS ANSWER FOLLOWS** [What follows is not a satisfactory answer and it contains an error. I am leaving it here since, according to me, errors are part of the development of mathematical ideas.]

> There always exists a continuous injection of $S_M$ into $S$; see **1**. This injection is a homeomorphism if $0$ is not a spectral value of $M$.

**1.** Take the square root of $M$ and rewrite 
$$S_M=\{ \langle M^\frac12 x | M^\frac12 x\rangle=1\}, $$
so the substitution $y=M^\frac12 x$ is such that $x\in S_M$ iff $y\in S$. This substitution indicates that the map $x\in S_M\mapsto M^\frac12 x\in S$ is a continuous injection. This map is a homeomorphism if $M$ is invertible with a bounded inverse, or equivalently, if $0$ belongs to the resolvent set of $M$. Since the spectrum is the complement of the resolvent this proves the claim in the box above.

---

The point that follows is an attempt to a counterexample, intended to show that the condition on the spectrum of $M$ cannot be dropped. However, **the example is flawed**.

**2**. [Suggested by Daniel Wainfleet]. In the real Hilbert space $\ell^2$, consider the operator
$$M \boldsymbol x=(x_1, x_2/4, x_3/9, \ldots, x_n/n^2,\ldots), $$ 
so that
$$
S_M=\left\{ \boldsymbol x\in \ell^2\ :\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n^2}{n^2}=1\right\}.$$
This set is compact [**FALSE**] so it cannot be homeomorphic to $S$.

Comment: Yes since $M$ is a positive operator on a complex Hilbert space, then $M^*=M$.

Comment: @Student: The map $x\mapsto M^\frac12 x$ injects $S_M$ into $S$. However, I think that you need the extra assumption that $M$ is invertible with a bounded inverse to ensure that this map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: If you change $M$  to let $Mx=(x_1,x_2/2^2,x_3/3^2,...)$   then $S_M$ is compact but $S$ is not.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Thank you for your contribution. I have a question. How can you say that $S_M$ is compact? It contains the unbounded sequence $$\boldsymbol x_m=(\underbrace{0,0,\ldots, 0, m}_{m\ \text{places}}, 0, \ldots),$$ so I suspect it is not.

Comment: The norm of $x_m$ in the norm $<Mx,x>$ is $1.$  Is the topology on $S_M$ to be to with respect to the Hilbert-space norm or  the norm $<Mx,x>$ ?

Comment: The topologie on $S_M$ is with respect to the Hilbert-space norm

Comment: $S_M$ is not compact.

Comment: @student : That's true, it is not. I don't know of the claim is true if 0 is a spectral value of $M$. It is true if $0$ is not spectral as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I think that the map $$h:S\to S_M,\;h:x\mapsto \frac{x}{\sqrt{\langle Mx,x\rangle}},$$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $$h^{-1}:S_M\to S,\;\;h^{-1}:y\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|}.$$

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro So I think the claim is always true.

Comment: @Student: It may be that you're right, of course. However, if I plug $x=y/\|y\|$ into $x/\sqrt{\langle Mx , x\rangle}$ I don't get $y$, so the second map is not the inverse of the first. Am I wrong?

Comment: If we take $$g:S_M\to S,\;\;g:y\mapsto \frac{y}{\|y\|}.$$ I think we can show that $h(g(x))=x$ and $g(h(x))=x$ So $g=h^{-1}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right! I thought it was more difficult than that. This works for any pair of norms, actually, but you use continuity of $M$ to ensure continuity of $h$.